# Stuck at installing JAX-RS facet while importing maven project in Eclipse 2021-06

Tags: eclipse, maven, jax-rs

[image]

I am importing maven project and this stuck here since last 1 hour. What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing STS(spring tools suite) solved my problem.